# Tizen. The work of JS when pressing “Back”

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

JS not working (not displaying the message "back") if show keyboard and press "back". Works with the second press - when keyboard is hidden.

```
document.addEventListener("tizenhwkey", function(ev) {
if (ev.keyName == "back") {
alert ('back')
}
})
```

Comment: Have you checked if window.addEventListener makes any difference?

Comment: It natural to hide the opened keyboard first when the keyboard is in visible mode. Isn't it ?

Comment: Not natural, if i want one click hide keyboard and close current display)